# Parse pandas df column with regex extracting substrings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text

I have a pandas df containing a column composed of text like:

```
String1::some_text::some_text;String2::some_text::;String3::some_text::some_text;String4::some_text::some_text
```

I can see that:

1. The start of the text always contains the first string I want to extract
2. The rest of the strings are in between "::" and ";"

I want to create a new column containing:

```
String1, String2, String3, String4
```

All separed by a comma but still in the same column.

How to approach the problem?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just apply a lambda function to do the operation you want to do (split first on ";", then split on "::" and keep the first element, and join them back):

```
df['new_col'] = df['old_col'].apply(lambda s: ", ".join(t.split("::")[0] for t in s.split(";")))
```

You could also avoid splitting on `::` since simply stopping before the first `:` is enough:

```
df['new_col'] = df['old_col'].apply(lambda s: ", ".join(t[:t.index(":")] for t in s.split(";")))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [136]: df.txt.str.findall(r'String\d+').str.join(', ')
Out[136]:
0    String1, String2, String3, String4
Name: txt, dtype: object
```

Data:

```
In [137]: df
Out[137]:
                                                                                                   txt
0  String1::some_text::some_text;String2::some_text::;String3::some_text::some_text;String4::some_t...
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'txt': ['String1::some_text::some_text;String2::some_text::;String3::some_text::some_text;String4::some_text::some_text']})
```

Comment: I actually checked the dtype of the column and it's "object". I can't manage to encode it because it says.. " UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 1679: ordinal not in range(128)" when I try: df.column.astype(str).

Answer (score 0):

consider the dataframe `df` with column `txt`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['String1::some_text::some_text;String2::some_text::;String3::some_text::some_text;String4::some_text::some_text'] * 10,
                  columns=['txt'])
df
```

[image]

---

use a combination of `str.split` and `groupby`

```
df.txt.str.split(';', expand=True).stack() \
      .str.split('::').str[0].groupby(level=0).apply(list)

0    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
1    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
2    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
3    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
4    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
5    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
6    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
7    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
8    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
9    [String1, String2, String3, String4]
dtype: object
```

Comment: it works. but I don't understand why applying it the list method. How can I keep it as a simple new column in the previous dataframe?

Comment: @xxxvinxxx the list function turns an iterable into a list.  Assign this to a dataframe column and you have what you want.